# Convert Mat to byte[] - .net core

Tags: arrays, .net-core, emgucv

I'm trying to use EmgCV with .netCore and I want to post my image to an server.

How can I convert my Image (Mat or Image<Bgr, byte>) to byte[].
I cant convert it to Bitmap first, since im using .netcore and not framework. That's the way how I convert my byte[] to a Mat:

```
 byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
 Mat image2 = new Mat(4000, 6000, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
 CvInvoke.Imdecode(bytes, ImreadModes.AnyColor, image2);
```

Can someone help me to do it the other way round? I tried using this, but this doesn't work:

```
 Image<Bgr, byte> afterImage = diff.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
 byte[] afterbytes = afterImage.Bytes;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> afterImage = afterImageMat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();

byte[] afterbytes = afterImage.ToJpegData();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the bytes you receive are not raw bitmap bytes. Instead you receive a jpeg or png encoded image. Thats why you have to use Imdecode.

EmguCV also offers method [Imencode](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.3.0/document/html/374e5128-e2bc-4ffe-c250-c20fb45788f0.htm) to encode images into various formats.

Example below encodes image2 Mat as jpeg bytes. Can also be png or something else when supported by EmguCV.

```cs
    var buffer = new VectorOfByte();
    CvInvoke.Imencode(".jpg", image2, buffer);  //Must use .jpg not jpg
    byte[] jpgBytes = buffer.ToArray();
```

Instead of Mat you can also pass Image<TColor,TDepth>